# How to write ( ) / ; characters with Caps Lock on?

Tags: release-juno

this is my very first time using anything other than Windows and so far I'm loving it. Everything looks very promising and it itches me to test and try it out more. But I got one little problem which is stopping me from that and that would be that, in order to write special characters like ; : ' * etc., I have to hold the shift button down. As I am being used to write those characters with the Caps Lock on, this is quite irritating and stopped me more than one time in my writing flow. Changing my layout doesn't seem to work and as I am still new to Linux I don't know what else I can do in order to just press Caps Lock, write my special character and press Caps Lock again to keep writing in an pleasant pace.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: Fixed that problem myself with the help of this site.

http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_shift_lock_key.html

I've changed the behaviour of my Caps Lock button, to be a Shift Lock instead.

Copy `sudo setxkbmap -option caps:shiftlock` in your terminal, hit enter, enter your password and your Caps Lock funtions now like a Shift Lock.

But unfortunately it wouldn't stay like this after you reboot the computer. So to not always type in the same command in the terminal, I added the following command to the applications who are getting automatically as soon as I log in.

Go to Settings -> Applications -> Applications who are getting automatically started when you sign in -> add a Application -> copy `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option caps:shiftlock` to where "enter custom command" stands -> enable your custom command.

With this edit I don't boast with it. I just want to help out other Linux newbies like I am one myself, so that they don't have to search a whole week for a solution like I did.

---

Issue: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard/issues/244

Comment: This CAPS LOCK logic is indeed very strange and definitely should be fixed. I guess you should report this issue to elementary OS developers @ https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-keyboard

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link. I opened a new issue on Github about this and hope that it will get solved soon.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer bellow and mark it so.